# MediaFormat required for Mediacodec

Tags: android, h.264, android-4.2-jelly-bean, decoder

I am trying to decode a h264 file using media codec. As it is not directly supported by Android, I am configuring my own decoder. For that I've attempted as follow.

```
codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
format.createVideoFormat("video/avc", /*640*/320, /*480*/240);
try {
    codec.configure(format, null, null,0);
} catch(Exception codec) {
    Log.i(TAG,"codec_configure " +codec.getMessage());
}
//codec.start();
codec.getInputBuffers();
codec.getOutputBuffers();
inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
```

I am getting `NullPointerException` at `format.creatvideoformat()` and also `IllegalStateException` at `codec.start()`

Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you be invoking `createVideoFormat` on the `MediaFormat` class, rather than on an instance of the class? According to the documentation the method is declared `static`.

Comment: For example: `format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the `createVideoFormat` could be

```
format = MediaFormat::createVideoFormat("video/avc", /*640*/320, /*480*/240);
```

Comment: Ya i got that just after posting the que.
that was a stupid one.
thanks anyway!!